# Android AVD won't start

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Eclipse Kepler
Debian 7.6
Android SDK R23.0.2 ( ~/android/tools/android )

After configuring an AVD thru the command line

```
~/android/tools/android avd
```

When I try to start it, the programme exits providing the log bellow and the AVD is not launched.

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getScreenResolution(HeadlessToolkit.java:224)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdStartDialog.getMonitorDpi(AvdStartDialog.java:441)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdStartDialog.createDialogContent(AvdStartDialog.java:189)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.ui.GridDialog.createDialogArea(GridDialog.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector.onStart(AvdSelector.java:1116)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector.access$200(AvdSelector.java:86)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector$3.widgetSelected(AvdSelector.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.AvdManagerWindowImpl1.open(AvdManagerWindowImpl1.java:146)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.AvdManagerWindow.open(AvdManagerWindow.java:94)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showAvdManagerWindow(Main.java:437)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:379)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
```

Of course it doesn't work better inside the Eclipse IDE and seems not to be invoked at all (no log in the console).

Any idea ?

Comment: move to genymotion ?

Comment: No I now develop on real android terminals

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case some packages were missing.
I followed the official website steps for Ubuntu troubleshooting and fixed the issue.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools

If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine, you need to install additional packages first. For Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) and above, install the `libncurses5:i386`, `libstdc++6:i386`, and `zlib1g:i386` packages using apt-get:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386 "
```